# Background-image opened style tag in html file not showing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

In an HTML file I have the following

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  color: #1e90ff;
  background-image: url("abc.png");
     }
</style>
```

The html file is in the same directory as abc.png

The color change is working

I am using the tornado web server to launch a flask app and i get the following warning in my terminal

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /abc.png (XX.XXX.XXX.XX) 0.61ms
```

My image is not displayed, I have tried everything that i found here and it was unsuccessful. Even changing the file permissions (chmod).
Thanks

Comment: Use a colon, not an equals sign.

Comment: Post your HTML too

Comment: You might try troubleshooting the CSS by changing the image URL to an external URL of another image, an absolute path of your image, and an external URL of that image.

Comment: It looks like it is trying to get the image from root level of the web server. Are you possibly using the following CSS: url("/abc.png")?

Comment: @patrickhawley The only thing that worked was changing the image URL to an external URL of another image. Thank you. But I am still troubled that loading it from the directory didnt work

Comment: I suspect this is a Python Tornado issue. Have you checked the documentation? I'm not familiar with it, but it's possible you need to be more explicit about the file location. What happens if you try to display the image as an img and not as a background-image? And what happens if you name the directory? (E.g., "/name-of-dir/abc.png")

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because the static files are being served by Tornado. If this is the case then you'll have to mention the static_path in the tornado settings.

Something like this:

```
handlers = [
(r"/", BaseHandler),]

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(PATH, "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(PATH, "static"),)

app = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
```

Now, keep all your static files inside the static directory and all templates in the templates directory.
Also, your style tag will now look like

```html
<style type="text/css">
body {
  color: #1e90ff;
  background-image: url("{{static_url('abc.png')}}");
     }
</style>
```